# How to create a resource library for using images in different projects? c#, winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a single icon storage in a library for use in different projects.
But after adding the icons to the library resources and creating the link in the project, it is only possible to add icons from the local computer resources, i.e. the library is not involved at all, but the opposite is necessary. How can I export icons from the library? How to create a connection with the project?

Comment: Add to the Library a static method which returns a Resource object by name, so instead of `Properties.Resources.IconName`, you can have `MyLibrary.GetImage("IconName")`. You could also use an enumerator, which returns the available resources as values: `public enum LibEnum { SomeImage, SomeOtherImage, AnIcon, AnotherIcon }` and call your method as `MyLibrary.GetImage(LibEnum.AnotherIcon)`, so applications that use the Library don't have to *remember* the Resources names, the enumerator lists what's available.You can also have a static method that returns the names of all available resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to make it possible to use pictures from the library already in the designer, before compiling the project?